# How to send HTML element ie. entire DOM document through fetch POST?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, post

I am still new to node and express...

I am running into issues trying to send document.body through a fetch POST request...

Long story short, I need to take data from an iframe, convert it to a pdf / image, collect them, zip them, and then send a download link..

I am stuck on sending the variable I have assigned to what the document.body was.. 
ie: `fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/htmltopdf", {method:"post", mode: 'no-cors',body:{htmlContent: document}});`

Any tips and leads are greatly appreciated..

Comment: Is it something intended to work only on a local machine?

Comment: It looks like there are two stories in your question ... "_HTML element_" as it is in the title of the question: `body:{htmlContent: document.documentElement.outerHTML}`. "_document.body_" as it is on the text of the question: `body:{htmlContent: document.body.outerHTML}`.

Comment: No, I intend to eventually deploy it as a heroku server. Using outerHTML still gives `{}` as a response on the server when I run `console.log(req.body)`

Comment: I appreciate the help!

Comment: You can pass data in the string format only via http.

Comment: You need to set proper content type and also since the body is an object you need to stringify it. `fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/htmltopdf", {method:"post", headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }, mode: 'no-cors',body: JSON.stringify({ htmlContent: document.body.outerHTML })});`

Comment: @Molda `.outerHTML` is a string already, can't be restringified.

Comment: @Teemu i didn't say anything about stringifying outerHTML. The data he wants to send is an object `{ htmlContent: document.body.outerHTML }` which is essentially `{ htmlContent: '<body> .... </ body>'  }` and that needs to be strigified.

Comment: I've tried `JSON.stringify()` and it also returns a blank `{}` object request. Is there something special I need to do for express to receive and handle this POST route?